# bash script exits unexpectedly when rebooting remote server through ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, reboot, remote

I have a bash script (on the local machine) that has the following line

```
ssh root@remoteip "some commands; shutdown -r now"

#do other things
```

However, after this line (the remote server was rebooted successfully), the whole bash script just exits ("do other things" is not executed).

How to fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by do other things? is that a part of your script? It's a little bit unclear what you are asking for!

Comment: Ya, "do other things" are a part of the bash script

Comment: You don't have to fix it, it's not a bug or unexpected behaviour. What you can do, though, is create 2 different cripts: **i)** `"some commands; shutdown -r now"` and **ii)** `do other things`. Where the **ii** is ran after reboot.

Comment: Is there anyway to tell the ssh remote command to ignore the output (just issues those commands, no need to care for the output, and continue with `do other things`)

Comment: @MBecerra, OP's script runs on the local machine, not on the one that gets rebooted.

Comment: Ya, the script is on the local machine, that's why I have mentioned about remote ssh. I will update the question now to make it more clear.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Thank you for pointing it out :) @aye, maybe you can let the script wait some time before proceeding to do the `# other things` using  `sleep 2m` or `sleep 120`, so that the remote server has time to reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the `shutdown` command in background, this did the job for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@remote-ip "some-command > /dev/null; shutdown -r now &"

uname -a
```

- `some-command > /dev/null`: runs `some-command` and redirects the output to `/dev/null`, so I don't get any output as you said.
- `shutdown -r now &`: runs the `shutdown` command in background and leaves the shell for getting further commands.
- `uname` is my `#do other things` for test purpose, which will be executed right after remote system is going down; )does not waits for it to be complete).

There are other ways to achieve this result too, e.g you can run the whole command in background:

```
ssh root@remote-ip "some-command > /dev/null; shutdown -r now" &
```

Or run it in a sub shell:

```
$(ssh root@remote-ip "some-command; shutdown -r now")
```

Although I suggest the first one, meaning running the `shutdown` command in the background of remote machine.

Comment: The first way is perfect. The other two ways seem a bit hacky because probably they may leave a running SSH process until some timeout occurs.

Comment: Yeah, I did an update ;)